# Why do Function properties are defined on the object itself (e.g. Function.name), but methods - on Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

[From the API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) properties are defined like `Function.name`, and methods like `Function.prototype.call()`. But in the code I still invoke them in the same way, for example:

```
function Foo() {console.log("inside Foo")}
console.log(Foo.name);  // Foo
Foo.call();             // inside Foo
```

I.e. I simply put a function name(Foo), then a method/property I want to use. Then why in API do I see properties defined on `Function`, and methods - on `Function.prototype` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing methods in the `prototype` allows you to share them among all instances, instead of duplicating them for each one.

For example, the behavior of `Function.prototype.call` does not depend on which function is called. It only needs a reference to the function (received via `this` argument) in order to call it later.

However, intrinsic data like `name` must be stored in the function object itself. It can't be stored in the `prototype` because each function instance has its own `name`. Well, it could be store as an internal [[Name]] property, and accessed via a getter and setter  defined in the `prototype`, but the data would still need to be stored in the function.

Note there are non-method properties defined in the `prototype`, e.g. `constructor`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

Functions (in general) can be shared among instances, so they go in `prototype`.

Properties are per-instance, so go in the constructor.

Comment: But in general, I can add a property to `prototype`, and then this property will be shared as well, can't I ?

Comment: Only *non-default* properties are per-instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually some argument for placing the *default values* of *immutable values* (or objects that are not mutated, by contract) in the prototype for common/expected properties.

Re-assignment of the properties will always be in the 'current this' object (well, object on which the assignment occurs). So if properties are assigned later - in the constructor or even after that - they will be 'promoted' to properties of the actual instance and not the prototype<sup>1</sup>.

However, since the difference (if any) is very modest, and dependent upon situation, it is *common practice* just to dump all the property assignments in the constructor. Per-object properties would need to be set individually anyway, regardless of the approach used.

Sharing *mutable* properties in the [prototype] can get questionable as then the property (when mutated) acts akin to a static variable; mutating shared objects should always be done with care.

---

<sup>1</sup> The only observable difference as to 'where' default properties are assigned is if `hasOwnProperty` is used.

Interesting related-ish read: [Should I put default values of attributes on the prototype to save space?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/28360) (And yes, I know this disagrees with my vary first sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight misconception here. You can define properties and functions (methods) on the function itself. You can define properties and functions that you want the object that the function construct on the prototype. It's not the same thing.

For example, the `.create()` method of the base `Object` constructor is defined as as `Object.create()` but the `.hasOwnProperty()` method of object instances is defined as `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`.

For example, if you have an object `mango` created from the constructor `Fruit()` then:

```
mango.weight(); // method comes from Fruit.prototype.weight()
Fruit.isFruit(mango); // method comes from Fruit.isFruit()
```

In particular, the `this` inside `Fruit.isFruit()` refers to the function `Fruit()` while the `this` inside `Fruit.prototype.weight()` in the above example refers to the object `mango`.

If you are used to OO programming from other languages, the difference is between static and non-static class members.

Answer (score 1):

`prototype` properties (such as the method `Foo.prototype.call`) are accessible using **instances** of the object, while direct properties (such as `Foo.name`) are accessible through the object itself (and not its instances) like *static* properties.

In your example there is a big difference between `Foo.name` and `Foo.prototype.call`, in order to use `Foo.name` you can call it directly, while in order to use `Foo.prototype.call` - you need to create an instance, and then it'll be available

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype.call = funciton(){console.log('I was called');}
Foo.name = 'My name is';

console.log(Foo.name); //My name is

var instance = new Foo();
instances.call(); //I was called
```

Another thing you need to notice is that both `name` and `call` has a native definition in the `Function` object type in JavaScript - therefore when you call `Foo.call()` - you call the `Function.prototype.call` method (which is just like calling `Foo();`, with one small difference that doesn't affect in this case)